# Json schema if/else/then not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, ajv

I have a usecase where based on one property I want to validate keys of an object on a regex pattern and on a different regex property if that does not match. Now for the particular const value defined in if it is indeed picking up the regex of then but for other values it is not picking else condition. I am using AJV validation.

My schema looks like this ->

```js
"properties": {
  "location": {
    "title": "Path",
    "type": "string",
    "description": "The relative JSON path of the location to which the properties should be set",
    "examples": ["abc", "def"],
    "pattern": "^.*$"
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": "Properties",
    "type": "object",
    "description": "The set of properties that shall be set on the given relative path",
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "propertyType": {
          "const": "123"
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[-&/_.:a-zA-Z0-9]+$": {
          "anyOf": [{
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "type": "number"
            },
            {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "else": {
      "patternProperties": {
        "^.*$": {
          "anyOf": [{
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "type": "number"
            },
            {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

in then I have a specific regex here which does not allow whitespaces if propertyType value is 123, if it's not 123 it allows whitespaces.

Now for this data it indeed does not allow whitespaces and fail with validation. ->

```
{
  "type" : "xyz",
  "anchor" : {
  "propertyType : "123"
},
setProperties : {
  "random_123 " : "value1"
}
}
```

but it fails with the same validation of then even if propertyType is not 123.

```
{
  "type" : "xyz",
  "anchor" : {
   "propertyType : "456"
},
setProperties : {
  "random_123 " : "value1"
}
}
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample looks quite confusing. But I think you are just mixing up the validation levels where your condition and the `patternProperties` is applied. The following simplified schema is working fine:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "propertyType": {
        "const": "123"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "patternProperties": {
      "^[-&/_.:a-zA-Z0-9]+$": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "type": "string" },
          { "type": "number" },
          { "type": "boolean" }
        ]
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "else": {
    "patternProperties": {
      "^.*$": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "type": "string" },
          { "type": "number" },
          { "type": "boolean" }
        ]
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

This JSON is valid:

```
{
    "propertyType": "123",
    "foobar": "baz"
}
```

This one is not valid:

```
{
    "propertyType": "123",
    "foo@bar": "baz"
}
```